# Change value of session bean with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, session, javabeans

So I have a session bean which is used as a flag, whether to show a list of items or a grid of items... This value can change in several ways in my page (to click on certain command button, to click on an item from a menu, to click on other command button, etc)

Now I use a hidden input on my page to get the value from the bean (which has a certain type by default)

```
<h:inputHidden id="viewType" value="#{myBean.viewType}" />
```

On my javascript function I assgin the value to this input and then show the correct view type with others js function...

```
   function setProdViewGrid(){
        document.getElementById('catPage:viewType').value = "grid";
        showProdGrid();
    };
    function setProdViewList(){
        document.getElementById('catPage:viewType').value = "list";
        showProdList();
    };
```

This works, but the problem is that on the bean, the attribute viewType isn't updated, just the input value (which makes total sense). Since my bean is session type I want to change & keep this value, is there a way to do it through js? Here are my bean side functions

```
public void setProdViewList(){
    viewType = "list";
}
public void setProdViewGrid(){
    viewType = "grid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to JSF to change the value of the variable "viewType" in the bean, it must have a getter (getViewType()) and a setter (setViewType(...)) (or have public access).